# Galois Theory. Why does this construction work?

Tags: galois-theory

I am attempting to solve equations with Galois theory. I find the following method works:

For an equation, such as $x^3+x-1=0$, assume it splits as $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=0$ in $\mathbb Q(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Put $\theta_1=(x_2x_3^2-x_1x_3^2)+(x_3x_1^2-x_2x_1^2)+(x_1x_2^2-x_3x_2^2)$, one calculates that $\theta_1^2=-27$ and therefore $\theta_1=\sqrt{-27}$.

Next let $\alpha$ be the solution of equation $\alpha^2+\alpha +1=0$ and put $\theta_2=x_2x_3^2+\alpha^2 x_3x_1^2+\alpha x_1x_2^2$ (or $\theta_2=x_1+\alpha^2x_2+\alpha x_3$ which might be better), one then calculates that $\theta_2^3=\left(\frac{\theta_1-3}{2}\right)^3-27$ and therefore $\theta_2=\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{\theta_1-3}{2}\right)^3-27}$.

Now we know we can calculate $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\theta_1,\theta_2)$.

My question is, why does $\theta_1=(x_2x_3^2-x_1x_3^2)+(x_3x_1^2-x_2x_1^2)+(x_1x_2^2-x_3x_2^2)$ and $\theta_2=x_2x_3^2+\alpha^2 x_3x_1^2+\alpha x_1x_2^2$ work? In fact $\theta_1=\left(e+(123)+(132)\right)\left(e-(12)\right)x_2x_3^2$ and $\theta_2=(e+\alpha^2(123)+\alpha(132))x_2x_3^2$.

The reason I construct such $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ is because when $\mathbb L=\mathbb K(\theta)$ is a Galois extension with $\mathrm{Gal}\, (\mathbb L/\mathbb K)=S_3$, then with $\theta_1=\left(e+(123)+(132)\right)\left(e-(12)\right)\theta$, the Galois group of $\mathbb K(\theta_1)$ in $\mathbb L$ is $\{e,(123),(132)\}$.

In the above case, $x_2x_3^2$ is one choice of $\theta$ since it has 6 conjugates: $x_2x_3^2,x_3x_2^2,x_1x_2^2,x_2x_1^2,x_1x_3^2,x_3x_1^2$, and none of them seem to be the same in general.

However, the problem here is in some specific case, for example $x^3+2=0$, $x_2x_3^2=x_3x_1^2$ holds occasionally so $x_2x_3^2\in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$. So there is actually no guarantee that $x_2x_3^2$ has 6 different conjugates.

I don't know how to explain why this method works.

Further more, does this construction work in general? Or does it just happen to work in case of degree 3,4?